# RegExpExecArray.groups == undefined when called inside angular library

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, angular-library

I've created an angular library containing a video player. Inside the library I'm using a regex with named capture groups. But when using the library, I can see that the `RegExpExecArray.groups` is `undefined`:

[image: Regex groups undefined]

This is the result of the following code, called from within the angular library:

```
let input = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqQ9NWzIiM4';
let test = new RegExp(/http[s]{0,1}:\/\/(www\.){0,1}youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(?<id>[^&]+)/, 'g').exec(input);
console.log('test', test);
```

Now when I use the exact same code snippet in my angular app, this is the result:

[image: Regex groups contains named groups]

```
let matches = new RegExp(/http[s]{0,1}:\/\/(www\.){0,1}youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(?<id>[^&]+)/, 'g')
  .exec('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqQ9NWzIiM4');

console.log('matches', matches);
```

Why is `RegExpExecArray.groups == undefined` when I use it within an angular library?

The code for the library is hosted on Github:

- Code for the library

  - [Here I need to extract the information from different types of urls](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-video-player/src/lib/components/video-player/video-player.component.ts#L628)
  - [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-video-player/tsconfig.lib.json)
- Code for the angular app:

  - [Here I've written the exact same lines of code that would be executed from the library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/implement-video-player-2/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.ts#L144)
  - [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/implement-video-player-2/MP.Web/ClientApp/tsconfig.json)

I'm strongly suspecting that my `tsconfig` files are the culprit of this, however I've already tried putting them the same, without luck.

angular library `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "types": [ "node" ],
    "lib": ["dom", "es2018"]
  }
}
```

angular app `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: consider using the `URL` to parse urls

Comment: I ended up targetting `es2015` to have it working. Angular still generates bundles for es5 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a "double escaping" issue here. It happens when the system parses the string first and pads it with escape characters at the special ones; '/', '?', ... then checking it out against the regex again.

For that, you can play this trick using `String.raw` followed by content inside daggers `` :

```js
let input = String.raw`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqQ9NWzIiM4`;
let test = new RegExp(/http[s]{0,1}:\/\/(www\.){0,1}youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(?<id>[^&]+)/, 'g').exec(input);
console.log('test', test);
```